# [couldNotConvert]userId on api/login with FusionAuth

Tags: fusionauth

We are testing FusionAuth as a auth solution for our applications.

We installed FusionAuth trough docker, everything is up and running.

Within the dashboard we made a test application with a test user but when we
try to log this user is with its credentials it gives the following error:

```
    "fieldErrors": {
        "userId": [
            {
                "code": "[couldNotConvert]userId",
                "message": "Invalid userId on the URL [index]. This must be a valid UUID String (e.g. 25a872da-bb44-4af8-a43d-e7bcb5351ebc)."
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

We are posting this trough postman as json to : http://localhost:9011/api/login/

```
{
 "loginId":"test@test.nl",
 "applicationId":"e2e45cc3-6710-4af9-b3c2-2d6f6cbbceed",
 "password":"***********",
 "ipAddress": "192.168.1.42"
}
```

What are we doing wrong? The user has a user id but it looks like it does not get resolved?

The version we are using of FusionAuth is 1.13.2

Answer (score 0):

Remove the slash from the end of the URL and it should work. Your URL should be: `http://localhost:9011/api/login`.

In FusionAuth, URLs need to be exactly as they are in the docs. If you add a slash, it will make it look like a different resource. The `PUT` method for the Login API does take additional information in the URL but the `POST` method doesn’t.

Also, ensure that you are using `POST` for the HTTP method.

Comment: Ahh okay thanx. The resource with the slash address would give errors specific to the resource required parameters for instance: missing password field. So it would seem that the correct endpoint was being hit. Why is this? Normally you would assume an 404 endpoint not found. Or am i missing something?

Comment: Technically, those two URLs point to different resources. This looks like a bug in the MVC we are using though. The MVC is appending `index` to the resource because this is how Apache normally resolves URLs that end in a slash. I'll open a bug for this so we can take a look at getting a better error message.

Comment: Thanx for the information. Another question maybe you could help with. Can fusionauth be used as a token exchange (STS). 

So the flow would be: 

* User log in with the api login. 

* User gets access token and id token. 

* Access token is then send to to the token exchange to get a jwt token and the id token is checked by the introspect endpoint.

* The jwt token is then send trough an api gateway that points to different microservices. 

* The microservice then checsk ik the jwt token in trusted/authenticated by the token exchange. 

Any idea how to do this with fusionauth?

Comment: Yes, this use case can be accomplished in FusionAuth. In FusionAuth both the Access Token and Id Token are both JWTs, and you can use our Introspect endpoint in your gateway configuration. https://fusionauth.io/docs/v1/tech/oauth/endpoints

Comment: Okay many thanx for the information. One last question. So the introspect then works as a token exchange or only as validation? Validstion would seem sufficient because the access token is already a valid jwt token.